# Moving user authorization out of Liferay

Tags: java, security, liferay, keycloak

Can anybody share some ideas how to completely remove user authentication and authorization from Liferay? The idea behind is to move all the user management and put this responsibility to some other Identity Providers, for example Keycloak. I am currently struggling to understand how Liferay is authenticating user against its database.

I have a class which extends Action class and the run method which is hit when click on submit button in login formular

```
public class CustomTemplateVarsAction extends Action { 
@Override
public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ActionException {
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    User user = themeDisplay.getUser();
```

How to make the whole mechanism, which would redirect to eternal providers (Keycloak or WSO2) and let the user type username and password there and only catch JWT token in case of success and allow user to log in on my portal?

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: something like that ? https://web.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/78695724

Comment: Yes, something like that, expect that this plugin is for 6.2+ and we are using only 6.1 version :(

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented that for Liferay 7 and Keycloak with `Open ID Connect` protocol last year. The approach is utilizing the documented Liferay 7 plugin points.

- com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.auto.login.AutoLogin
- com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.LiferayFilter

actually extending abstract classes

- com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.auto.login.BaseAutoLogin
- com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter
- com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action

It intercepts all request to Liferay and redirects for login to the IdP (i.e. Keycloak), then it handles the incoming access token by validating it against Keycloak (back-channel call). For a valid access token it imports (or updates) the data of the authenticated user into Liferay's database by extracting the user's data from the access token. That also includes roles and organization associations!
Another challenge is token refreshing (which also keeps the Keycloak session alive) and support for participating in global logout (GLO). Therefore another filter on Liferay side is necessary, that recognizes the special Keycloak logout request and terminates the corresponding Liferay session.

Furthermore, the usage of a REST client from inside Liferay (which is needed to call Keycloak APIs) can be tricky. The OSGi bundling for JAX-RS client is incomplete and due to classloader problems can only be fixed by a custom ClientBuilder factory. But if you use Jersey or RestEasy directly without JAX-RS, it might not be such a pain.

To be honest. Implementing all this in a professional, stable and secure way takes several months. Particularly if you have to do a lot of research in the Liferay code. Its documentation for this kind of work is insufficient.
There are two open source projects available on github that are addressing this topic.

- https://github.com/GluuFederation/oxRay
- https://github.com/finalist/liferay-oidc-plugin

However, the oxRay seems not to be maintained anymore and it does not support Liferay 7 (which requires OSGi).
The other one was still too immature at the beginning of last year, but might have improved now.

Comment: I wrote Gluu plugin for liferay 6, we are upgrading it to 7. It will be release soon. And your right, it move authentication out of liferay, but liferay will still maintain it own user database which would be use for all internal operation.